# object moving with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to move my "robot" div where i clicked , so  i wrote a javascript code :

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  let robot = document.querySelector('.robot');
  robot.clientTop = event.pageX + 'px';
  robot.clientLeft = event.pageY + 'px';
});
```

```css
.robot {
  background-color: rgb(10, 0, 143);
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="robot">
  <span class="eyes_left">
    
                </span>
  <span class="eyes_right">
    
                </span>
  <div class="hands">

  </div>
  <div class="battery">
    <div class="charge">

    </div>
    <div class="charge">

    </div>
    <div class="charge">

    </div>
    <div class="charge">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't  work and don't say any errors whats the problem ??

Comment: Give it "position: absolute;" in css. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatly you cannot set the clientTop in the way you have tried. You need to use css to adjust the position. Give the element position: absolute and then update the top and left position in the javascript.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  let robot = document.querySelector('.robot');
  robot.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';
  robot.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
});
```

```css
.robot {
  background-color: rgb(10, 0, 143);
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="robot">
  <span class="eyes_left">
    
                </span>
  <span class="eyes_right">
    
                </span>
  <div class="hands">

  </div>
  <div class="battery">
    <div class="charge">

    </div>
    <div class="charge">

    </div>
    <div class="charge">

    </div>
    <div class="charge">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this method.

```js
let robot = document.querySelector('.robot');

document.addEventListener('mousedown' , function (event){
    let y = event.pageY + 'px';
    let x = event.pageX + 'px';
    robot.setAttribute('style', `top:  ${y}; left:  ${x}`);
    console.log(`Position Updated, top:  ${y}; left:  ${x}`)
});
```

```css
.robot{
    background-color: rgb(10, 0, 143);
    height:120px;
    width:120px;
    border-radius:15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="robot">
            <span class="eyes_left">

            </span>
            <span class="eyes_right">

            </span>
            <div class="hands">

            </div>
            <div class="battery">
                <div class="charge">

                </div>
                <div class="charge">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="charge">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="charge">
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientTop
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientLeft

`clientTop` and `clientLeft` are read only properties

Comment: Please include this as a comment if this doesnot provides a solution  to the issue